# AVD not getting created (No response)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new to Android development. 
I tried creating AVD in AVD manager. 
I have installed both ARM EABI v7a system image and Intel x86 atom system image.
when I clicked Ok . there is no response from the AVD manager and it's getting hanged.
These are the parameters I have selected.
[image: screenshot of avd creation]
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think Your sd card size is too big. The AVD is a very slow emulator, maybe You have to set less size on sd card like 100 or something...

Comment: thank you! problem solved. the device get started. is there any better emulator than AVD to try?.

Comment: Genymotion is better emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Android Emulator is always very slow and very inconvenient for developers.
Yes it have many features but the poor performance is always a let down.Even if you install HAXM Accelerator.

I'd recommend switching to a much better option, [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com)